# Maven3 activate profile via property

Tags: maven, maven-3

There is POM:

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    {...}
    <properties>
        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
        <skipTestExecution>false</skipTestExecution>
        <skipSpecTests>${skipTests}</skipSpecTests>
        <skipSpecTestExecution>${skipTestExecution}</skipSpecTestExecution>
    </properties>
    {...}
    <profiles>
      <profile>
        <id>no-test-compile</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>skipSpecTests</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
      </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Can I activate no-test-compile profile via skipTests property? Of course I can create new one profile with skipTests activation property, but I think there is more elegant way to do it.
Thanks.

P.S. Explicit profile definition is undesirable.

Comment: Is using `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` from command line an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

And what about `mvn clean package -DskipTests=true -Pno-test-compile`?

Comment: @AndrewOrlov Explicitly defining the profile is the best way to do this. Less ambiguous and certainly simpler to implement. Otherwise just set the property value explicitly from the command-line and avoid profiles completely